# Playing a stream of bytes on the iPhone MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, video-streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller, rtmp

I have a stream of bytes that represent a movie with H264 video and AAC audio. I got it using an RTMP library (rtmp-dump) and the data is comming through the network to my iOS simulator.

However I have no idea how to show it to the user. The MPMoviePlayerController seems to accept only an URL. Is there a way to play videos by supplying something like a NSPipe or similar to the player?

Comment: Could you please comment on whether the custom URL route worked for you? Or did you resort to NSPipe?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could try implementing a custom URL protocol (see [NSURLProtocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLProtocol_Class/Reference/Reference.html)).  Basically you create the protocol and register it, then any in-app requests to load a url having this protocol will be routed to your protocol instance.  You'd likely have to mimic the responses that a HTTP server would send for a progressive-download of the file.

This wont work if MPMoviePlayerController uses lower-level CFNetwork calls vs. NSURLConnection to make its requests.  This question implies that MPMoviePlayerController DOES make use of NSURLConnectino:  [How to play movie with a URL using a custom NSURLProtocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383388/how-to-play-movie-with-a-url-using-a-custom-nsurlprotocol)

Also read the [URL Loading System](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Concepts/URLOverview.html) docs.